# Get the length of an element inside of an array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the length of elements inside of an array.

```
var test = ["hi", "bye"];
```

How can I get the length of `test[0]` (`"hi"`) or `test[1]` (`"bye"`)?

In my main code, I have stored a value inside a array. The value it has been stored is this "svars alternativ_4" in array[0]. I tried to get the length by doing like this array[0].length but it is giving me the wrong length. It is giving me 20 and if I remove that value it will say the same.. why?

Comment: Um... `test[1].length`?

Comment: js arrays have zero based indices.

Comment: be careful, indeces of the array start at 0, so it will be test[0].length and test[1].length

Comment: Hmm, still I get wrong length of the values that has been stored into the array..........

Comment: @user3478007 - You may have trailing spaces or something. Try `test[0].trim.length`.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
test[0].length    //for "hi"
test[1].length    //for "bye"
```

Comment: In my main code, I have stored a value inside a array. The value it has been stored is this "svars alternativ_4" in array[0]. I tried to get the length by doing like this array[0].length but it is giving me the wrong length. It is giving me 20 and if I remove that value it will say the same.. why?

Comment: @user3478007: Maybe the value is not what you thing it is.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over the entire array:

```
for(i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  test[i].length // do something here with the length
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If test array is of type string which it is due to the fact that its contents are enclosed in quotes. You can store the contents of test[1] in a string variable and get the length by calling the length() method. Something like this
    String temp = test[1] ;
    Int len= temp.length();

Comment: In my main code, I have stored a value inside a array. The value it has been stored is this "svars alternativ_4" in array[0]. I tried to get the length by doing like this array[0].length but it is giving me the wrong length. It is giving me 20 and if I remove that value it will say the same.. why?